# CMD batch file to delete a file if not found in list from text txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a bat to delete all files with the RELATIVE name that are NOT contained in a text file

In the text file list.txt i have this:

```
C:\S-ATLANTICO-1\MEDIA\Innplay-Logo.mp4
C:\S-ATLANTICO-1\MEDIA\logo-FB_sep.png
C:\S-ATLANTICO-1\MEDIA\logo-news_sa.png
```

and the in the same folder have this files:

```
Innplay-Logo.mp4
logo-FB_sep.png
logo-news_sa.png
Carlos.jpg
Sapo.png
list.txt
```

So i need to delete the next files because not exist in list.txt

```
Carlos.jpg
Sapo.png
```

but i also MUST KEEP the LIST.TXT

i have tried this but without sucess

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=C:\S-ATLANTICO-1\MEDIA"
set "excludeFile=C:\S-ATLANTICO-1\MEDIA\list.txt"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%folder%" ^| findstr  /vig:"%excludeFile%" ^| findstr /v /i "\list.txt"') do del "%folder%\%%F"
```

any one can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Why a .bat file specifically?

Comment: Problem: you compare output of `dir /b` (`file.txt`) with content of exclude file `C:\path\file.txt`, so you won't get correct matches. Easiest way to overcome this: `for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%folder%" ^| findstr  /vlig:"%excludeFile%" ^| findstr /vli "%excludefile%"') do @echo del "%%F"`, but be aware that `dir`switch /s` gives full path/filenames, but also fles from subfolders. (may or may not be a problem in your case)

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, this works ok, but i will have problems with sub folders... thanks

Comment: You probably won't have problems, but it slows things down considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.  It works for my testing.

I have placed ***echo*** statements instead of actually ***deleting*** anything.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=C:\S-ATLANTICO-1\MEDIA"
set "excludeFile=%folder%\list.txt"

:: Check that both the target folder and filter file exist before starting up.
if not exist "%folder%" echo %~nx0: The target folder doesn't exist.  Nothing to do.&& goto :EOF
if not exist "%excludeFile%" echo %~nx0: The list file doesn't exist at the location specified!&& goto :EOF

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%folder%"') do call :process_file "%%F" "%~0" "%excludeFile%"
goto :EOF

:: --------------------------------------------
:process_file
:: --------------------------------------------
set input_file=%~1
set this_batch=%~2
set list_file=%~nx3

:: Skip list file and this batch file too
if "%this_batch%"=="%input_file%" echo Skip this batch file&& goto :EOF
if "%list_file%"=="%input_file%" echo Skip list file&& goto :EOF

:: Grep for the include file in the list 
findstr /C:"%input_file%" "%excludeFile%" 2>&1 1>NUL

:: Bail out if the input line was in the list file
if not errorlevel 1 echo Skip "%input_file%", it is in %list_file%&& goto :EOF

:: Delete anything left
echo delete file %input_file%&& goto :EOF
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Yes, we 'could have' done it with less code but this (IMHO) is easier to read and control the behavior of.  Others will disagree I am sure. :^P

Comment: Gracias @Señor CMasMas but i can get this work... i dont see any action, i put your code in a CMD file and nothing...

Comment: Also.. @lit has a nice solution but it isn't in batch.  If you are comfortable with powershell, you might give that a try too. :)

Comment: Hi... This works Good.. Can i Check first if folder and file.txt exist??  If exist gostaria to process. Thanks

Comment: Con mucho gusto amigo.  I added it to the code above.  ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Hi @Señor-CMasMas , can you help me on this... i also need exclude files with tmp extension... Thanks.. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It iterates over the contents of `$thedir` and deletes files that are not in `list.txt` and are not scripts. Put these two (2) files in the same directory. It would be best not to put them in the same directory as the files being deleted. Run the .bat file from a cmd.exe shell.

When you are satisfied that the correct files will be removed, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

=== Remove-Except.ps1

```
$thedir = 'C:\src\t\delexcept'
$precious = (Get-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $thedir -ChildPath 'list.txt')) +
    @(Join-Path -Path $thedir -ChildPath 'list.txt')

Get-ChildItem -Path $thedir -Exclude 'list.txt','*.ps1','*.bat' |
    Where-Object { (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and
        ($precious -notcontains $_.FullName) -and
        $_.FullName.StartsWith($thedir) } |
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf }
```

=== Remove-Except.bat

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dpn0.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

On cmd line this should do

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('Dir /B /A-D ^|find /v /i "list.txt"') Do @findstr /IL "%~nxA" list.txt >Nul ||(echo del %A)
```

I'd include the `/E` switch with findstr if the last line in list.txt has a trailing cr/lf,
otherwise the last entry wouldn't match [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman).

If the output looks OK, remove the echo in front of del.

As a batch file:

```
@Echo off
set "folder=C:\S-ATLANTICO-1\MEDIA"
PushD "%folder%"
set "excludeFile=list.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
    Dir /B /A-D ^|find /v /i "%excludefile%"'
) Do findstr /IL "%~nxA" "%excludefile%" >Nul ||(
    echo del %%A
)
Popd
```